# Flask Url Rerouting

Tags: flask

I am working on a flask project where I have to redirect all urls ending with "/user" and "/user/" to "user/1".
Is there any other shorter way to do this than the one I have used below?

```
@app.route('/user')
def userReport(page_no):
   return redirect('/user/1')
@app.route('/user/')
def userReport(page_no):
   return redirect('/user/1')
```

And so on. Could I use a fucntion that automatically does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put both route definitions on the one function:

```
@app.route('/user')
@app.route('/user/')
def userRedirect():
   return redirect('/user/1')
```

Instead of redirecting, you could just have the `/user/<int:page_no>` route accept a default value when page number is omitted:

```
@app.route('/user', defaults={'page_no': 1})
@app.route('/user/', defaults={'page_no': 1})
@app.route('/user/<int:page_no>')
def userReport(page_no):
    # produce a user report
```